# Storing secure data in android

Tags: android, security

I am using OAuth 2 for login in my android app. Username and password are not stored on the device. However I have included three string parameters in the source code itself inside a class Constants.

```
public class Constants{
public static String redirectUri = "http://someurl/users/me";
public static String clientId = "my-android-app";
public static String clientSecret =    "asdfasf";

}
```

I access these parameters during login using Constants.clientId. My question is is my way of storing data secure? Do I have to encrypt these 3 datas. I cannot store these data in shared preference or database because in rooted device this data can be viewed.

Comment: what about code hardcoding??

Comment: I am not so sure but what I am doing is hardcoding string in java.

Comment: that is the best way i think,else encode as you said using some algorithm

Comment: my only concern is that android apk files are zip files and can be opened to view the contents. All the java classes are converted but can be reverse engineered.

Comment: You can use some algorithm to block re engineering, i am sure on that

Comment: and look this http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/04/using-password-based-encryption-on.html. some times it help you

Answer (score 1):

[OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations(rfc6819)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.1.1) has listed Obtaining Client Secrets as a threat.

And as Google doc Using [OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) says:

> These applications are distributed to individual machines, and it is assumed that these applications cannot keep secrets.

So there are no Client "Secrets" in fact. Trying to obfuscate a secret in installed applications is a futile effort as the secrets can always be recovered using the abundance of reverse-engineering and debugging tools.

Of course, you should do your best to protect secrets but at the end, a highly motivated hacker can always get it in an installed application. So it's the value of the secret vs. difficulty of extraction. The value of the client secret is impersonating the application. It doesn't give any access to user data.

My suggestions:
Just take the risk go ahead and obfuscate it. Or you can
consider using the proxy pattern([move the secret to a web server acting as an API proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419915/how-to-keep-the-oauth-consumer-secret-safe-and-how-to-react-when-its-compromis)).